# How to add input fields in pdf programmatically ? ( iOS )

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf

If it is not possible to add input fields in pdf I have another question to ask. Is there any solution for adding some content in existing pdf which already has input fields?

I can merge pdf files using these code:

```
NSString *cacheDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

// File paths
NSString *pdfPath1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pdf1" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSString *pdfPath2 = [cacheDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp.pdf"];
NSString *pdfPathOutput = [cacheDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"out.pdf"];

// File URLs - bridge casting for ARC
CFURLRef pdfURL1 = (__bridge_retained CFURLRef)[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:(NSString *)pdfPath1];//(CFURLRef) NSURL
CFURLRef pdfURL2 = (__bridge_retained CFURLRef)[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:(NSString *)pdfPath2];//(CFURLRef)
CFURLRef pdfURLOutput =(__bridge_retained CFURLRef) [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:(NSString *)pdfPathOutput];//(CFURLRef)

// File references
CGPDFDocumentRef pdfRef1 = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef) pdfURL1);
CGPDFDocumentRef pdfRef2 = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef) pdfURL2);

// Number of pages
NSInteger numberOfPages1 = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdfRef1);
NSInteger numberOfPages2 = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdfRef2);

// Create the output context
CGContextRef writeContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(pdfURLOutput, NULL, NULL);

// Loop variables
CGPDFPageRef page;
CGRect mediaBox;

// Read the first PDF and generate the output pages
NSLog(@"GENERATING PAGES FROM PDF 1 (%i)...", numberOfPages1);
for (int i=1; i<=numberOfPages1; i++) {
    page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfRef1, i);
    mediaBox = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox);
    CGContextBeginPage(writeContext, &mediaBox);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(writeContext, page);
    CGContextEndPage(writeContext);
}

// Read the second PDF and generate the output pages
NSLog(@"GENERATING PAGES FROM PDF 2 (%i)...", numberOfPages2);
for (int i=1; i<=numberOfPages2; i++) {
    page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfRef2, i);
    mediaBox = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox);
    CGContextBeginPage(writeContext, &mediaBox);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(writeContext, page);
    CGContextEndPage(writeContext);      
}
NSLog(@"DONE!");

// Finalize the output file
CGPDFContextClose(writeContext);

// Release from memory
CFRelease(pdfURL1);
CFRelease(pdfURL2);
CFRelease(pdfURLOutput);
CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdfRef1);
CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdfRef2);
CGContextRelease(writeContext);
```

but when I am trying merge a pdf containing input fields I got plain pdf which had no input fields. So how to keep input fields in pdf when merging?  Thanks...

Comment: See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415856/merging-pdf-file-with-annotation